# Save to IndexedDB beforeunload

Tags: javascript, promise, indexeddb, onbeforeunload

I want to save to IndexedDB before the user leaves my page. I'm doing this periodically, but since it's pretty big, I don't want to save too often.

my current (broken) code is as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
    persist(state);
});
```

Here, persist immediately returns a promise and the browser exists before I get the chance to save state.

Unfortunately, doesn't seem like IndexedDB has a synchronous API at this point.

Is there anything I can do to make the browser wait so i can store a value into IndexedDB?

Comment: there's no method for making asynchronous API synchronous - using beforeunload you can allow the user to cancel unloading the page, but you can't force them to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you instead save to localStorage on page unload. Then at a later time, check for this value in localStorage and move it into indexedDB when you have more time.

Comment: I actually moved from local storage to IndexedDB because of size limits... But that's a good suggestion.

Comment: Thinking about it some more - i can actually split my state into 2 parts - a small core that I _really_ don't want to lose, and bigger state that's ok to 'forget'.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

There can be something like a save button in your page first.

Then when the user closes the page you can show a dialog box for confirmation request on closing the page without saving. Eigther you can utilize this time to save the data or since this is informed to the user to save data, user can manually press the save button to save it.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. In my case i'd rather not dump this problem on the user if possible. I might just save more often...